# Assigning value of a filed (positional variable) into a user defined variable in gawk/awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am creating a variable called "size" and trying to assign a value to it from gawk positional variable. But, that does not seem to work. In the example below, I am trying to store the value of field 4 into a variable "size". When I print the variable size, entire line is printed instead just the filed 4.

How can I save the filed value into a variable for later use?

```
prompt>  echo "Live in a big city" | gawk '/Live/ {size=$4; print $size}'
```

The following is outputted:
Live in a big city

I would like to see just this:

big

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the dollar sign. awk is like C, not like shell or perl, where you don't need any extra punctuation to dereference a variable. You only use a dollar sign to get the value of the n'th field on the current line.

```
echo "Live in a big city" | gawk '/Live/ {size=$4; print size}'
```

The reason you get the whole line printed is this: the awk variable `size` is assigned the value `big`. Then, in the print statement, awk dereferences the `size` variable and attempts `print $big`. The string "big" is interpreted as an integer and, as it does not begin with any digits, it is treated as the number 0. So you get `print $0`, and hence the complete line.